# Cannot upgrade kernel 3.16 from 14.04 to 14.04.2

Tags: upgrade

anyony knows what may cause this error?

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
➜  log  apt-cache policy libqt5gui5 libgbm1
libqt5gui5:
  Installed: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2
  Candidate: 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14.2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.2.1+dfsg-1ubuntu14 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libgbm1:
  Installed: 10.3.0-0ubuntu2intel1
  Candidate: 10.3.0-0ubuntu2intel1
  Version table:
 *** 10.3.0-0ubuntu2intel1 0
        500 https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to **Intel Linux Graphics Installer**.

I solved downloading the proper package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgbm1)

```
sudo dpkg -i libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

and then, reissuing

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

the Ubuntu update will work.

Maybe you will have to run the intel-linux-graphics-installer after the reboot...